# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, poo, mvc

tengo un problemilla con el constructor de mi proyecto y es que tras realizar una consulta al servidor y devolver el numero de variables que el constructor me pide, me dice que solo manda 1 y que se esperaban 5.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Candidato::__construct(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\recuPHP\MVC\Final\Model\base.php on line 65 and exactly 5 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\recuPHP\MVC\Final\Model\candidato.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\recuPHP\MVC\Final\Model\base.php(65): Candidato->__construct(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\recuPHP\MVC\Final\Controller\index.php(5): ClaseExamen::obtieneCandidatos() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\recuPHP\MVC\Final\Model\candidato.php on line 20
```

Tengo la clase Candidato:

```
 class Candidato {
    protected $dni;
    protected $nombre;
    protected $apellidos;
    protected $sexo;
    protected $idiomas; //array de idiomas
      
    public function getDni() {return $this->dni; }
    public function getNombre() {return $this->nombre;}
    public function getApellidos() {return $this->apellidos;}
    public function getSexo() {return $this->sexo;}
    public function getIdiomas() {return $this->idiomas;}
    
    public function __construct($pdni,$pnombre,$papellidos,$psexo,$pidiomas) {
        $this->dni = $pdni;
        $this->nombre = $pnombre;
        $this->apellidos=$papellidos;
        $this->sexo=$psexo;
        $this->idiomas=$pidiomas;
```

Y tengo la función que realiza la consulta:

```
    public static function obtieneCandidatos()
{
$sql2= "SELECT c.dni, c.nombre, c.apellidos, c.sexo, id.nombre FROM candidatos c
inner join idiomas_encuesta i on c.dni=i.dni_candidato
inner join idiomas id on i.id_idioma=id.id;";

$resultado2=self::ejecutaConsulta($sql2);
$arrayCandidatos=array();

while ($fila=$resultado2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
                  $arrayCandidatos[]=new Candidato ($fila);
             }
        
         return $arrayCandidatos; 


}
```

Cuando quiero llamar a la función desde el controlador:

```
$arrayDatosPersonas=ClaseBase::obtieneCandidatos();
```

Me suelta el error, en teoría le estoy mandando los 5 atributos pero parece ser que no me los detecta. En la tabla idioma hay varios idiomas y no se si será ese el problema. Espero puedan ayudarme gracias.

Comment: Según lo que veo cuando le pasas `$fila` al constructor de `candidatos` en realidad no estas pasando 5 argumentos, sino 1 solo argumento: un array con 5 elementos. Intenta pasar `...$fila` como argumento a tu constructor.

Comment: Vale entiendo esto, entonces debería haber puesto algo como:  $arrayCandidatos[]=new Candidato($fila['dni'],$fila['nombre'], $fila['apellidos'], 
                   $fila['sexo'], $fila['idiomas']); no? @CamiloGomez

Comment: Si, asi mismo. El operador  [spread](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array) también debe funcionar (a menos que sea un array asociativo). Su función es "desempacar" el array. Seria algo como `new Candidato(...$fila)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás enviando un array:

```
$arrayCandidatos[]=new Candidato ($fila);
```

Entonces tu constructor debe tener la capacidad de recibir el array:

```
public function __construct($datos) {
        $this->dni = $datos['dni'];
        $this->nombre = $datos['nombre'];
        $this->apellidos= $datos['apellidos'];
        $this->sexo= $datos['sexo'];
        $this->idiomas= $datos['id_idioma'];
}
```

O en lugar de modificar el `contruct` modificar la instancia para que tenga la capacidad de enviar los datos individuales:

```
 $arrayCandidatos[] = new Candidato (
        $fila['dni'],
        $fila['nombre'],
        $fila['apellidos'],
        $fila['sexo'],
        $fila['id_idioma']
    );
```

Al ser un Array asociativo no se puede usar el operador `spread` [...$array](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array)
para que esto funcione tendrías que forzarlo con `array_values` (**Update** a partir e la versión 8 de PHP si funciona con array asociativos):

```
$fila = array_values($fila);
$arrayCandidatos[] = new Candidato (...$fila);
```

[Documentación Relacionada:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40663869/4717133)

Comment: Esto soluciona el problema, pero como he puesto arriba en comentarios, esa seria la forma de hacerlo sin cambiar el constructor?

Comment: la Segunda opción seria sin modificar el contruct.

Comment: la tercera opciones en programación php es la opción comprimida de la segunda.